# Spin div with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys i want to make div with items. But dont know how to ask question about it

On click going left or right and stop on random image. Someone can give me tips how to do that?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this 'roulette' is helpful to you: https://jsfiddle.net/3ufktby8/1/